# NullPointerException when setting variables to objects in ArrayList

Tags: java

I have an ArrayList containing Movie objects which I produced from a List containing File objects using this method:

```
// returns a list containing movie objects with correct names
private static ArrayList<Movie> createMovieObjs(Collection<File> videoFiles) {
    ArrayList<Movie> movieArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    Matcher matcher;

    for (File file : videoFiles) {
        matcher = Movie.NAME_PATTERN.matcher(file.getName());
        while (matcher.find()) {
            String movieName = matcher.group(1).replaceAll("\\.", " ");
            Movie movie = new Movie(movieName);

            if (!movieArrayList.contains(movie)) {
                movieArrayList.add(movie);
            }
        }
    }
    return movieArrayList;

}
```

Everything works fine in above code, getting correct ArrayList.

Then I want to parse info for each Movie object in this ArrayList and set that info to that Movie object:

```
     // want to parse genre, release year and imdbrating for every Movie object
    for (Movie movie : movieArrayList) {
        try {
            movie.imdbParser();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Parsing failed: " + e);
        }
    }
```

Here is Movie.imdbParser which uses Movie.createXmlLink (createXmlLink works fine on its own, so thas imdbParser  - tested both):

```
private String createXmlLink() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(XML_PART_ONE);
    // need to replace spaces in movie names to "+" - api works that way
    String namePassedToXml = this.title.replaceAll(" ", "+");
    sb.append(namePassedToXml);
    sb.append(XML_PART_TWO);
    return sb.toString();
}

// parses IMDB page and sets releaseDate, genre and imdbRating in Movie objects
public void imdbParser() throws IOException {
    String xmlLink = createXmlLink();

    // using "new Url..." because my xml is on the web, not on my disk
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(new URL(xmlLink).openStream(), "UTF-8", "", Parser.xmlParser());
    Element movieFromXml = doc.select("movie").first();

    // using array to extract only last genre name - usually the most substantive one
    String[] genreArray = movieFromXml.attr("genre").split(", ");
    this.genre = genreArray[genreArray.length - 1];

    this.imdbRating = Float.parseFloat(movieFromXml.attr("imdbRating"));

    // using array to extract only year of release
    String[] dateArray = movieFromXml.attr("released").split(" ");
    this.releaseYear = Integer.parseInt(dateArray[2]);

}
```

Problems seems to be with accessing Movie objects, it doesn't create good XMLLink so when it tries to access genre in XML it throws NPE.
My error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.michal.Movie.imdbParser(Movie.java:79)
at com.michal.Main.main(Main.java:52)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Movie.java:79 is:

```
String[] genreArray = movieFromXml.attr("genre").split(", ");
```

and Main.java:52 is:

```
             movie.imdbParser();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: It's not, I know what NPE is, just can't find a way to fix my particular problem.

Comment: inspect the downloaded xml, maybe the movie element does not have a genre attribute

Comment: `movieFromXml.attr("genre")` possibly returns `null`, you should check it. That perhaps happens when there is no attribute "genre".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of errors such as this are caused by the data not being as you expect.  Often when dealing with a lot of data then sometimes it can be just a single record that does not "conform"!

You say that this line is causing you problems;

```
String[] genreArray = movieFromXml.attr("genre").split(", ");
```

So split the line down and debug your application to find the issue.  If you can't debug then export the results to a log file.

1. Check that movieFromXml is not NULL.
2. Check that movieFromXml contains a "genre" attribute as you expect
3. Check that the data in the attribute can be split as you expect, and produces a valid output.

Often, it is good to view the data being retrieved prior to this call.  I often find it useful to dump the data out to file and then load it in an external viewer to check that it is how I expect.

Answer (score 2):

When you make a chain of calling method like this: `movieFromXml.attr("genre").split(", ")`, you have to make sure that each of the preceding element is not null. In this case, you have to make sure that `movieFromXml` is not null and `movieFromXml.attr("genre")` is not null.